# DirectorySearcher/LDAP lookup fails from IIS deployment environment, works from console on same machine

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, ldap, iis-8

We have some code executing in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  The application is hosted in IIS on Windows Server 2012.  The identity of the app-pool is not standard, but rather a specific user, e.g. `iis-appPool-username` noted below.  The application is running in .NET 4.0 w/ Integrated Mode set for the Managed Pipeline.

- I've tried it both with and without specifying the username in the `DirectoryEntry` object.
- I can run a console app that does the same thing, as the very same user (command.exe run as the same user, that is) on the same machine, and it works.
- It should be noted that the console app did *not* work until I manually specified the LDAP path *and* `AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer`, as it is hitting a read-only domain controller.  It was giving me the same error for the console app until I specified the LDAP path and Readonly type.  However, while console app works now, while the IIS app does not.

The code is below.

```
// also tried: var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://DC=subdom,DC=ourdomain,DC=com");
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://DC=subdom,DC=ourdomain,DC=com", @"domain\iis-appPool-username", "password");
searchRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer;

using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
{
    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName={0}))", "someGroupName");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

    // This is where the failure happens
    var result = searcher.FindOne();
}
```

The error w/ stack trace looks like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007054B): 
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.get_SearchRoot()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

EDIT: Also, it is the very same error if I explicitly use the *wrong* username and password.  From my local machine, if I use the wrong username and password, I get an auth error.  However, from IIS, with the wrong username and password, it doesn't even get that far.

EDIT: I specified in the web.config to run with full trust:

```
<securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

And we also gave the user admin priveleges on the box.  Continue to get the same error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.`

UPDATE:  So, this ended up being a combination of 2 problems.

1) As @Hans noted below, I was originally missing the `DirectoryEntry` parameter to `DirectorySearcher`.  In my quest to try different possibilities, combinations, I managed to miss that change when I had a working console application and was updating the application code to reflect it.

2) When I added the parameter to `DirectorySearcher`, I was still getting the error.  The message was identical, and the stack trace was *almost* identical.  There was 1 line different in the middle of the stack trace - a secondary call to another method that needed the `DirectoryEntry` argument to use in it's own `DirectorySearcher`.  I had been looking at the problem for so long, that my eyes were only seeing the same error message and what appeared to be the same stack trace, when in fact it was a new one.  Passing my `DirectoryEntry` object to those calls fixed that problem.

The ultimate solution did *not* require that I have a server identifier in the path (but your mileage may vary on that if your environment cannot resolve the domain controller without it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the search root for the `DirectorySearcher` class in order
to connect to the Active Directory domain controller.
You will get a *COM Exception (0x8007054B)* if you do not
specify a search root for the `DirectorySearcher` class.

Try the following lines of code instead:

```
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://DC=subdom,DC=ourdomain,DC=com", @"domain\iis-appPool-username", "password");
searchRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer;

using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)) // Specify the search root here
{
  searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName={0}))", "someGroupName");
  searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

  var result = searcher.FindOne();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have tried so many different things I accidentally left it off of my example.  I have in fact tried passing in the searchRoot to the `new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)`

Comment: @Matt: Did you try using a server to bind to your DC (LDAP://servername/dc=subdom,dc=dom,dc=int)? Does you Web App run under a domain account?

Comment: I have not tried a server bind, that's a good idea.  I am using a domain account.

Comment: @Matt: I've tested in my test environment that you also get this COM Exception if the your account/box is not able to determine the name of the domain controller.

Comment: no luck on the server bind.  I'm pretty sure the domain is visible on that box by that account, since it works in a console app "run as" that user.

Comment: @Matt: Does you web app really runs under the same account. Did you double check it using the task manager. There you should see a w3wp.exe process running under the account?

Comment: Yeah, confirmed using Sysinternals process explorer.  So - an interesting revelation.  I created an ASP.NET MVC3 app, whose sole purpose is to have a /Home/Index action that returns the result of this lookup.  Set it to the same user, same app pool settings (just did a side-by-side compare) and the sample app ... works.

Comment: @Matt: Really interesting... In my test environment I've used a Web Forms Web App. I will test it using a MVC 4 app. Then I will come back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Your very first answer ended up being the solution - but as I describe in my update above I was seeing the same error, but in a different place ... but had been staring at this problem so long thought it was the same.  I really *really* appreciate it. edit: will award bounty when SO allows me to do so.